# Error connecting PostgreSQL remotely

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin

I have a problem when I try to connect remotely with a PostgreSQL database. I am working in local PC and I have the database in a server. In the server I configure both pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf. First file looks like:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             46.18.24.0/22           trust
host    all             all             193.106.180.0/22        trust
host    all             all             193.146.230.62/32       trust
```

And the second one:

```
listen_addresses = '*'                  
port = 5432             
max_connections = 100
```

I am sure that port 5432 is opened in the server side.

However when I try to connect from my PC (193.146.230.62) via pgAdmin III, I cannot. What could the problem be?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: 46.18.24.0/22, are you sure about the 22? I would expect a 24 in here. And change "trust" into "md5" again, you don't trust any attempt without a correct password. Did you restart PostgreSQL after changing postgresql.conf and reload pg_hba.conf after changes? An error message would by nice as well, makes it easier to help you.

Comment: hey try this `193.146.230.62             255.255.255.0` instead of this `193.146.230.62/32`

Comment: I tried both 193.146.230.62 255.255.255.0 and 193.146.230.62/32, but it doesn't connect

Comment: you should include error messages on both, including where you have checked and not found error messages.

Comment: What happened with this? You seem to have abandoned the question.

Comment: I wrote a full length tutorial here! you can check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424267/setting-up-django-and-postgresql-on-two-different-ec2-instances/13433627#13433627

Answer (score 2):

Is there a firewall on the server, or a 3rd-party add-on firewall on the PC?

If the server is Linux, check `sudo iptables -L` and see if there's anything there. A default, no-firewall configuration is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     
prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     
prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     
prot opt source               destination
```

On a Windows server, check Windows Firewall to make sure that `postgres.exe` is allowed to listen and/or that the port is open.

On a Windows client, check to see if there is a 3rd party "internet security" or firewall program installed. If only Windows Firewall is on there it's fine, that won't be the problem. Some 3rd party firewalls block *outgoing* connections, though, and could be the source of your problem.

Check to see if you can `ping` the server.

If this doesn't help, **please edit your question to add the exact words of the error message you get** and a description of *how* you are connecting (psql, PgAdmin-III, JDBC, whatever).

Once you have connections working, **make sure to change `trust` back to `md5` and set user passwords**. Running with `trust` mode pretty much says "Hey, anybody who can get on my network , come steal or destroy my data if you want".

Answer (score 0):

Please see the log of PostgreSQL for detail，may be you should set the parameter log_connections=on
  and log_disconnections=on of the $PGDATA/postgresql.conf file

by the way ,I suggest you use md5 authentication methods instead of trust。

Answer (score 0):

try changing `listen_addresses` to your server's local ip and specifying `/24` mask in `pg_hba.conf`, as PresleyDias suggested.

Answer (score 0):

How about to try changing the pg_hba.conf.
Simply change 127.0.0.1/32   to 0.0.0.0/0

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             46.18.24.0/22           trust
host    all             all             193.106.180.0/22        trust
host    all             all             193.146.230.62/32       trust
```