# connect heroku django app with ec2 postgres database

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-ec2

I have a django app running on heroku. It works well with the heroku provided 5 mb database.

I have an ec2 instance, where I have installed postgresql database and have setup the database based on the following answer [Setting Up Django and PostgreSQL on two different EC2 instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424267/setting-up-django-and-postgresql-on-two-different-ec2-instances)

I have added custom TCP port 5432 in Security Groups for PG.

To connect my heroku app with postgresql database on EC2, I try the following

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=\
postgres://my_database_name:my_database_password@\
<Public_DNS>:<PORT>/my_user_name
```

Having done this, I try to do `heroku run python manage.py syncdb` and then I receive the error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "......compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Please let me know, what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to the PostgreSQL database from your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether host's still available. I think that could be the issue.

what does `heroku config | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL` show ?

Does it give the same host as seen in

```
"could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "......compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```