# Restarted Database Server can no longer be accessed by webserver

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I had to stop then start my ec2 database server running postgresql.  Now after it is started, i get the following error message from my django web server

> could not connect to server: Connection refused   Is the server
>   running on host "54.235.119.193" and accepting    TCP/IP connections on
>   port 5432?

However because I use elastic IPs and reassigned the same IP (54.235.119.193) I don't think that is the issue. I also am using the same security groups as before, which allow 5432.

I think the only thing that changes when you start/stop is the internal IP but I don't remember using that anywhere in configuration

Any Ideas?

Comment: dont hardcode the IP address, instead use the elastic ip of the host.

Comment: I am using the elastic IPs

Comment: Did you modify your security group?

Comment: What does your pg_hba.conf look like, where it relates to that IP or subnet? Is there an entry for IP 54.235.119.192?

Comment: The pg_hba.conf is unchanged from when it was working. It references the elastic IP of the web server, not itself (the database server)

Comment: You don't need an Elastic IP for your PostgreSQL. With its internal IP , you can work in the same way. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424267/setting-up-django-and-postgresql-on-two-different-ec2-instances

Comment: How long have you waited to try this out before restarting? Maybe the elastic ip/dns was fully "refreshed" yet

Comment: Also how confident are you that no changes to the conf file were made since your last restart. Any changes may not have taken affect until this restart. I had a similar issue with nginx recently and turned out i made a typo when i was reviewing the conf file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using iptables or selinux?  These usually get in the way on restart if not configured properly.