# Browser Says Cannot Connect to PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, database-connection

I'm running a Red Hat Linux server using Amazon EC2 with PostgreSQL/Apache and have encountered some issues. When I try to access my app in browser, I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to the database
could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running on host "my-private-ip-address" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

However, I am able to access my database using the following command in PuTTY. I can also connect to my database in pgAdmin.

```
psql -U username -h my-private-ip -d dbname
```

I have edited my `pg_hba.conf` and `postgres.conf` files using the instructions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424267/setting-up-django-and-postgresql-on-two-different-ec2-instances) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545298/connect-to-remote-postgresql-server-on-amazon-ec2), but unfortunately they did not work for me. My inbound Security Group settings are as follows:

```
Type              Protocol     Port Range      Source
Custom TCP Rule   TCP          5432            Anywhere    0.0.0.0/0
HTTP              TCP          80              Anywhere    0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS             TCP          443             Anywhere    0.0.0.0/0
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

**Edit:** I just tried disabling SELinux and then it was able to connect to the database with no errors in the browser. But I would like to keep SELinux on for enhanced security. I guess this issue is somehow related to file permissions or firewall settings.

**Edit v2:** I think I have solved it, but I would still like someones opinion if this is the right thing to do. I found the following command [here](http://virtuallyhyper.com/2012/09/selinux-and-httpd/) to allow Apache and PostgresSQL connect with each other:

```
setsebool -P httpd\_can\_network\_connect\_db on
```

Comment: Do your app and db live on the same server

Comment: @JoeLove Yes they do. I've just edited my question. I used `setsebool -P httpd\_can\_network\_connect\_db on` to allow Apache and PostgreSQL to talk to each other.

Comment: have you tried using localhost for your app config instead of the actual IP? Depending on your server you could use a unix socket which is likely faster.

Comment: @JoeLove Yes I did try `localhost` and it was resulting in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache and PostgreSQL were not talking to each other. To enable the connection between them, use the following command:

`setsebool -P httpd\_can\_network\_connect\_db on`

Hopefully this will help someone in future.